# Android WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading not working with HTTPS

Tags: android, webview

Is shouldOverrideUrlLoading not called when using HTTPS URLs?

Main Activity Code:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

MyAppWebViewClient Code:

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

public static final String TAG = "MyAppWebViewClient";

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}
}
```

With the code above, shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not getting called. If I change the loadURL line to the one below, it works:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation stating this limitation on HTTPS vs. HTTP - any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Omg. I faced the same problem. It's weird that no one answered to it for about 3 years.